# Cucumber- Enconding não aceita variável com acento

Tags: java, engenharia-de-software, cucumber, testes

no meu teste de software feito no cucumber em um cenário especifico eu atribuir uma string a uma váriavel:

Parte do Cenário: "Entao o sistema apresenta a mensagem "Usuário ou Senha Inválidos!"

A string "Usuário ou Senha Inválidos" está atribuida a váriavel `LoginIn`:

```
     public static void validarLoginInvalido(String LoginIn) throws Exception {
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        System.out.println("o valor da mensagem recebida foi: "+alert.getText());
        assertEquals(LoginIn, alert.getText());
        //assertEquals("Usuário ou Senha Inválidos!", alert.getText());   
}
```

No meu `assertEquals` comparo a minha string passada no cenário com a mensagem apresentada na tela do sistema que é: **Usuário ou Senha Inválidos!**

Ou seja na teória o assert iria passar pois as mensagens comparadas são exatamente iguais, porém o eclipse me apresenta o seguinte erro:

> **org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<Usu[�rio ou Senha Inv�]lidos!> but was:<Usu[ário ou Senha Invá]lidos!>**

O enconding do cucumber é o UTF-8, já tentei alterar o enconding do projeto para: ISO-8859-1 e o mesmo é apresentado.

**OBS:** O codigo comentado no exemplo acima :

`assertEquals("Usuário ou Senha Inválidos!", alert.getText());`

Comparando as duas string e passando o texto de forma estatica funciona normalmente.

Comment: no feature você marcou a lingua e o encoding? tipo : # language: pt
# encoding: iso-8859-1

Comment: Sim, testei o enconding UTF-8 e o ISO-8859-1, ambos apresentam o mesmo erro